# Cannot access Remote PC through VPN while behind DD-WRT router?

Tags: ip-address, ip, vpn

Random question about IPs for you.

I have a weird problem where I can connect to my company VPN, but cannot access my system with IP address 192.168.1.117.

I am behind a DD-WRT router at home. I was wondering if anyone knew if for some reason you cannot get LAN IPs while connected to VPN? Or is there a config setting that will allow a 192.x.x.x IP to route to my work PC?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are several possible reasons, depending on multiple variables which you haven't specified, but the simple explanation is likely to be what while connected to your work VPN, you work routing rules are being applied for traffic and this means that it is routing 192.168.1.117 over the VPN tunnel to your work, and not to your LAN.

I also have a DD-WRT router setup at home. A similar scerario which applies to me is the following:

When dialed into the VPN, my web browser loads my work web proxy settings and want to use those. My work web proxy settings want to route traffic directed at 192.168.1.x to my company proxy server, whereas what I actually want is to keep that traffic local to my home LAN.

Solution: for Firefox, use the FoxyProxy add-on and have a setting for "Home" and "Work", where the home setting tells it that for traffic 192.168.1.x to keep it on the local LAN and *not* use the proxy setup.

For Chrome there is a similar add-on called Proxy Switchy which does the same thing.

In addition, you can setup DD-WRT to act as a local DNS nameserver. This will assign a local domain name to all machines on your local network ( . ) meaning that whether connected to the VPN or not, a fully qualitied hostname yourhost.yourdomain will resolve correctly to your network, and not try to find that hostname on your work network over the VPN. This is very useful: see http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DNSMasq_as_DHCP_server

Answer (score 0):

Too add on to liamf's background information, I've found that putting my LAN on the 192.168.2.x/24 network can usually solve the routing issues. Sometimes the VPN will add rules to route all of your traffic through the tunnel, and then you would have to manually add rules to not use the tunnel for your 192.168.2.x/24 network.